# View SQL Server Table Hierarchy in ms access

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access

I am working on replacing an old ms access system with an SQL server one with a C# front end. Unfortunately I have some die hard ms access users who will be accessing the SQL server tables from ms access but to them it should essentially look the same.

When tables are created in ms access and a relationship is created between them they show in a hierarchical view with a + sign to get to the lower table in the hierarchy.

Is there a way to replicate this when using linked SQL Server tables? I have tried replicating the relationships in SQL server with ones in ms access but it had no effect.

Comment: Your comments "unfortunately" and "die hard" are needlessly negative with respect to MS Access.

Comment: I have years of experience of crashes, bugs and general speed issues. The speed issues generally relating to 2007 especially designing reports. I find lots of wasted development time investigating seemingly random bugs, cleaning the mdb... And this is following ms access best practices. I'm sure it's fine for small projects but they have a tendancy to keep being used and added to.

Comment: I have years of experience with no crashes, bugs or general speed issues. Perhaps the difference between you and me is not in Access.

Comment: @David we can take a poll I think I know what the outcome would be. I can corrupt a db just by opening it in terminal services for instance. Or make a report ultra slow by using an sql 2000 linked table in access 2007.

Comment: I can kill an automobile engine by never replacing the oil. This doesn't mean there's something wrong with the automobile or its engine. Free clue: if you want help with Access, you need the good will of the people who work with Access all the time. Badmouthing Access is going to tend to drive those people away. By all means, if you're just posting the question as some form of public wanking and not actually seeking real help, go right ahead and insult the tools you're [mis-]using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if cascading datasheets work or not with SQL Server tables/views. But I do know that you can create a datasheet form and embed a datasheet subform and when you display it as a datasheet, you get the plus signs, i.e., the cascading datasheet structure. It's not as flexible out of the box as non-form cascading datasheets, but if you wanted to, you could build the functionality to swap datasheet subforms the same way you can swap different related tables.

Ask if you need more detail.

Comment: You are correct I can obtain the view I want this way. It took a little playing around with relationships and the form designer but it is doable.